# Underscore as key in redis

Tags: redis

When key in redis contain a underscore hmget and hmset are not working anymore
i think redis do not support underscore in key name.

Is there a solution for this when rebuilding a complete database is impossible.

```
$values = array('value1'=> 1, 'value2'=> 'hello', 'value_three'=> 'this is value 3');
```

$redis->hmset('key1', $values);

$redis->hset('key1', 'value_three', 'this is my new value 3');

Comment: I have never experienced this issue. Are you sure it is not caused by the programming language interacting with redis? To make sure this is not the case, do some testing from the CLI with direct redis commands.

Comment: This doesn't sound right - Redis doesn't care about the key's or field's name. This is probably an issue with how you're using it. Please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it do not work if i use hset but after some testing if i again call hmset to update the values it work.